# Unexpected element '{urn:jboss:domain:keycloak:1.0}subsystem

Tags: wildfly, keycloak, wildfly-9

Happy New Year to all.
I have a keycloak/wildfly question.

I am attempting to secure my war for WildFly 9.0.2.Final deployment.  I follow the directions in section 7.2.1 of http://docs.jboss.org/keycloak/docs/1.0.4.Final/userguide/pdf/keycloak-reference-guide-en-US.pdf

I get the error **Unexpected element '{urn:jboss:domain:keycloak:1.0}subsystem**

I have carefully followed each step as listed below.

1. cd $WILDFLY_HOME
2. unzip keycloak-wildfly-adapter-dist.zip
3. edit the standalone.xml and add the following:

   ```
   <server xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:1.4">
   <extensions>
   <extension module="org.keycloak.keycloak-wildfly-subsystem"/>
   ...
   </extensions>
   <profile>

   <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:keycloak:1.0"/>
   ...
   </profile>
   ```
4. It is the line **subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:keycloak:1.0** that is flagged in the error.

What am I missing?  Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't have a good answer for you, other than probably you're missing some jar's from your classpath.  But why keycloak 1.0.4 and not the latest 1.7.0?

Comment: As mentioned by @JohnAment, that's a pretty old version of Keycloak that you're using. More recent versions come with a jboss CLI script that does the configuration in a more robust manner. Editing the standalone.xml file is fraught with danger, especially if your server is running.

Answer (score 0):

May be it's a little bit too late. I think the problem could be that you forget to merge modules, bins folder from key-cloak into Jboss, so that the container itself doesn't recognize the keycloak.